# Javascript - forEach varibale is not defined and setAttribute won't work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, frontend

I'm trying to get *setAttribute("disabled", true)* to work with an array of checkboxes. So far, I've created an if statement that checks through the array and if one of them is checked, return "checked" to the console.log. Within the same statement, I've added a foreach statement to set the checkboxes of a different array to disabled if any of the boxes in the first array are checked. I get an error which says "day has not been defined". How can I solve this?

```
        <center>
        <div class="col-2">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the day(s) of the month the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DofMID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DofMNo)
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DofMInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline checkboxDofM" id= "checkboxDofM">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].DofMID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].IsChecked)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.DofMInfo[i].DofMNo)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="col-2">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the month(s) the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.monthID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.monthName)
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MonthInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline" id="checkboxMonth">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].monthID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.MonthInfo[i].monthName)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="col-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the day(s) the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.dayID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.dayName)
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DayInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline checkboxDay" id="checkboxDay">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].dayID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.DayInfo[i].dayName)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>


<script>

    const checkboxDofMElements = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxDofM');
    const checkboxDayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxDay');



    checkboxDofMElements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', event => {


        if (event.target.checked) {
            console.log("checked");

            checkboxDayElements.forEach(day in checkboxDayElements)
            {
                day.setAttribute("disabled", true);
            }

        }
            }));



</script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />

}
```

Comment: `.forEach()` expects you to pass a function, and your code is not doing that.

Comment: `checkboxDayElements` and `checkboxDofMElements` is a collection of `<div>` elements! (not your checkboxes) - And duplicate `id` attributes (as you generating in the loops) is invalid html

Comment: change foreach loop like this `checkboxDayElements.forEach(function(day,index){  //your code here });`

Comment: What steps can I take to solve this?

Comment: you can take the steps outlined in the comments above. Didn't you understand?

Comment: I'm trying this and it still allows me to check the boxes:             if (event.target.checked) {
            console.log("checked");

            checkboxDayElements.forEach(function (day, index) {
                day.disabled = true;
            })
                }
            }));

Comment: Again, `checkboxDayElements` is a collection of `<div>` and `day` is one of those `<div>` elements - it is NOT a checkbox (you cannot disable a `<div>`)